# Docusign radio button not pre-selected

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign API to create some radio buttons, and I'd like to be able to select one of the radio buttons programmatically, before the user opens up the form.

My attempts so far haven't worked.  With the code I've been using, either the radio button is not preselected, or I receive the following error:

> A Custom Tab is not Complete. A Custom Tab requires both a Name and a TabLabel. Radio tabs may only have one radio selected in a group.

Here's the code which appears like it should work, but I don't have a preselected radio button:

```
Radio rYes = new Radio();
rYes.AnchorString = @"\cb_yes\";
rYes.AnchorXOffset = "0";
rYes.AnchorYOffset = "-15";
rYes.TabId = "1";
rYes.Selected = "true";
```

Comment: I do not have much experience w/the C# library for this, but wondering if you were able to create any radio buttons? Please keep in mind that you will need to specify the value property, which sounds like it will be 'yes' in this example. Radio's need to be added to a radioGroup, and only one radio tab within the group can be selected = true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code where I was able to successfully create radio buttons, in which one of them has been selected programmatically:

```
Signer signer = new Signer();

Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

// add radio buttons
Radio rYes = new Radio();
rYes.AnchorString = @"\cb_yes\";
rYes.AnchorXOffset = "0";
rYes.AnchorYOffset = "-15";
rYes.TabId = g.ToString(); 
rYes.Value = "X";
rYes.Selected = "true";

Radio rNo = new Radio();
rNo.AnchorString = @"\cb_no\";
rNo.AnchorXOffset = "0";
rNo.AnchorYOffset = "-15";
rNo.TabId = g.ToString(); 

List<Radio> radioVals = new List<Radio>();
radioVals.Add(rYes);
radioVals.Add(rNo);

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup();
rg.GroupName = "radioGroup";
rg.Radios = radioVals;

List<RadioGroup> radioGroupTabs = new List<RadioGroup>();

signer.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs = radioGroupTabs;
signer.Tabs.RadioGroupTabs.Add(rg);
```